# FCM push notifications does not work if google services file is in product flavor directory

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented FCM push notifications in Android app, the product flavors are as below. Push notifications are working fine if the google-services.json file is in app\ directory. However, it stops working if the google-services.json file is moved to its respective product flavor directory. 
Is there any additional step that need to be taken care if the google-services.json is moved to its product flavor directory? Appreciate any suggestions.

```
productFlavors {
    Staging {
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        buildConfigField STRING, DOMAIN, STAGING_DOMAIN
    }

    Production {
        buildConfigField STRING, DOMAIN, RELEASE_DOMAIN
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you add all packages in the setting of firebase and get config google-services.json?

Comment: Yes, google-services.json is fine because push notifications are working right if the file is in app/ directory, it fails if I move it to flavor directory.

Comment: I also use product flavor as you, and I added all packages to setting of firebase. I don't split to 2 folders as you split (Production and Staging), just let the google-services.json in the app folder. As I saw you have 2 package above, Do you add `yourpackage` and `yourpackage.dev` in firebase setting?

Comment: in firebase, I have two projects one for staging and one for production and each project has been set with its package name respectively i.e package.dev for staging and package for prod. Therefore I have two google-services.

Comment: @Babs have you solved this issue? I am also facing right now.